# Unable to setup second replicaset, while configuring getting error "_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, replicaset, database

I have setup 3 nodes configured with replicaset rs0 starting on Node1 like: rs0-0 primary:Node1,
rs0-1 Secondary:Node2, 
rs0-2 Secondary:Node3.

Its working fine as I login on respective nodes i get

```
rs0:PRIMARY> on node1, rs0:SECONDARY> on node2 and node3.
```

I am using 27018 port common on all nodes for replicaset:rs0

I want to setup another replicaset rs1 starting on Node2, like            rs1-0 primary:Node2, rs1-1 secondary:Node1, rs1-2 secondary:Node3. Common Port 27019

I've logged in using command on Node2:

```
mongo --port 27019
>use admin
>db.createUser(
  {
   user: "admin",
   pwd: "a",
   roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
  }
 )
```

But Now I get this message

```
2016-04-12T03:32:41.526+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't add user: not master :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1230:11
@(shell):1:1
```

rs.config() output on Node1 of replicaset rs0

```
{
"_id" : "rs0",
"version" : 3,
"protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "host" : "mongodb1:27018",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 1,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "host" : "192.168.61.102:27018",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 1,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "host" : "192.168.61.103:27018",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 1,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
        "votes" : 1
    }
],
"settings" : {
    "chainingAllowed" : true,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
    "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
    "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
    "getLastErrorModes" : {

    },
    "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
        "w" : 1,
        "wtimeout" : 0
    },
    "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("570be6e9e1126efb1d168e8b")
 }
}
```

## MONGODB v3.2.4

Comment: What do you mean by **using 27018 port common on all nodes for replicates:rs0**? are you running MongoDB on separate physical machines? I'd suggest you to update post and include output from `rs.config()`

Comment: I mean **Node1:rs0-0: 27018, Node2:rs0-1: 27018, Node2:rs0-2: 27018**